# How to set Method level Transaction timeout in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: java, jboss, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have developed Java application and am using wlp18 server. Before that I have run my application using Jboss. In Jboss am using @TransactionTimeout annotation to set method level transaction time out in my EJB. When I migrate to WebSphere Liberty Am unable to find method level transaction timeout. Instead of that am using .xml configure to set class level transaction timeout like below,

```
 <session name="class-name">
   <global-transaction transaction-time-out="1000">
 <session>
```

Is there any way to set Transaction time out in method level or why it is not possible to set method level transaction in WebSphere Liberty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a `UserTransaction` object, you can set the transaction timeout using that:

```
@Resource
UserTransaction tx;

public void doSomething() {
  tx.setTransactionTimeout(123);
  tx.begin();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Working good. I have added annotation '@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)' 
 in my class level to change CMT to BMT